# Spring Cache perform action after expires

Tags: kotlin, spring-cache, caffeine-cache

I'm using Caffeine as Cache Manager integrated with Spring Cache to avoid multiple unnecesary file downloads. Once I download the file, I have its path, which is returned by the download method.

I would like to delete the file once the cache expires. I tried with `removalListener` but it seems it is only triggered when cache is manually cleared.

This is my cache configuration:

```
@Bean
fun getCacheBuilder() = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .removalListener { _: Any?, filePath: Any?, _: RemovalCause ->
        Files.delete(Paths.get(filePath.toString()))
    }

@Bean
fun getCacheManager(caffeine: Caffeine<Any, Any>): CacheManager {
    val caffeineCacheManager = CaffeineCacheManager("myStoredData")
    caffeineCacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeine)
    return caffeineCacheManager
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code? Is there any way to automatically trigger the listener when the cache expires?

Answer (score 2):

By default expiration is handled as a side-effect of other activity on the cache triggering a maintenance cycle. If the cache is idle then the notification will be delayed. To resolve this you will need a thread to schedule expiration events on, so that it can trigger a `cache.cleanUp()` call. This can be done using [Caffeine.scheduler(Scheduler)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/latest/com.github.benmanes.caffeine/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Caffeine.html#scheduler(com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Scheduler)) configuration. The `systemScheduler` relies on a Java 9+ feature of a JVM-wide scheduler thread.

```kotlin
Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .scheduler(Scheduler.systemScheduler())
    .removalListener { _: Any?, filePath: Any?, _: RemovalCause ->
        Files.delete(Paths.get(filePath.toString()))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Redis cache and @EventListener approach

For those who come here with the same question, but regarding Redis:

I've done this in next way, using Spring's `@EventListener`.

```java
@Slf4j
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)
@Configuration
public class RedisListenerConfig {

    @EventListener
    public void handleRedisKeyExpiredEvent(RedisKeyExpiredEvent<String> event) {
        String eventId = new String(event.getId());
        log.info("Key {} has expired. Value {}", eventId, event.getValue());
    }

}
```

The whole manual can be found here [Baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-ttl)

Working on Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.x.x as well as on Java 8 and Spring Boot 2.5.x